# C++ gcc error on operator= function

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

function definition

```
const circularLinkedList<Tp>& operator=(const circularLinkedList<Tp>& otherList);
```

lines that cause the error, error message refers to line 327, which starts at nodeType....

```
template <class Tp>
nodeType<Tp>* circularLinkedList<Tp>&::operator=(const circularLinkedList<Tp>& otherList)
```

And the error messages from the gcc compiler are:

```
circularLinkedList.h:327: error: invalid declarator before â&â token
circularLinkedList.h:327: error: expected initializer before â&â token
```

I assume that I have made some sort of syntax error in in defining this method somewhere. How would I have to go about fixing it? Thanks.

Comment: Is a `â&â` token simply a `&` token in oddly encoded quotes?

Comment: @MrLister - I think so.  Copy/paste problem maybe.

Comment: Isn't that & before ::operator wrong?

Comment: @abresas, that's the main problem.  The secondary problem is a type mismatch between const circularLinkeList<Tp>& and nodeType<Tp>*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post a little bit more code for us?  Can you explain what nodeType is?

The following looks like a function definition:

```
template <class Tp>
nodeType<Tp>* circularLinkedList<Tp>&::operator=(const circularLinkedList<Tp>& otherList)
```

However, for one thing, the declaration says it returns a `const circularLinkedList<Tp>&`.
Also, you don't want to have the `&` before the `::`.  It needs to be the type's name, not a pointer or reference to a variable of that type.  If you want that behavior you need to use a proxy class.

So it should be something like:

```
template <class Tp>
const circularLinkedList<Tp>& circularLinkedList<Tp>::operator=(const circularLinkedList<Tp>& other)
```

Which should *almost* invariably end with `return *this;`

Comment: It is a function definition, and does return *this. But you actually fixed it with that line. I wasn't sure how to get the function definition right, and couldn't make it work, until you answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block, you show the method declaration, not the function definition.
In the second code block, you show the header of the method definition.

Method Declaration:
Returns `const circularLinkedList<Tp>&`

Method Definition:
Returns `nodeType<Tp>*`.

You are not defining the method you declared.
You are defining some method you have not declared.

The header of the definition should be:

```
const circularLinkedList<Tp>& circularLinkedList<Tp>::operator=(const circularLinkedList<Tp>& otherList)
```